# Problem with converting ps to pdf if source was pdf type

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, postscript

I have source pdf file which I print and I fetch the .prn file via [MultiFilePortMonitor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mfilemon/). 

 I try then to convert this .prn file back to pdf whit the following Instruction:

```
gswin64.exe -dPDFA=1 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sColorConversionStrategy=/RGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="C:\targeFile.pdf" "C:\sourceFile.prn"
```

But when I am doing this, all the fonts are getting lost, I see normal looking pdf but it doesn't contain a searchable text anymore but seems to be a picture.

when the sourceFile is not an PDF but e.g a word File, everything works fine and I get a well formed searchable pdf file, and the fonts are embedded.

I have tried several gs-version 9.20, 9.22 and 9.26. Same Results.

What do I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The lack of searchable text is very likely to have occured when you printed the PDF file. Assuming you printed to a PostScript printer.

PDF no longer shares the same graphics model as PostScript; in particular it can contain transparency, which cannot be modelled in PostScript. The only way to represent a transparent PDF in the PostScript imaging model is to render the transparent areas (at least) to a bitmap image and include that.

Sounds to me like that is what is happening for you.

Moral of the story; if you have a PDF and you want a PDF, don't convert it to something else and back. Why are you doing that ?

Comment: I am doing that because I have written a software that processes documents that are printed through MFileMon Printer. My Problem is anybody could use this Printer and I don't know what the source File was. I only get the Postscript file and when this ps file was a PDF before I just can't process it anymore

Comment: Well, frankly, that's **your** problem. I've explained why it happens, and that it is, most probably, nothing to do with Ghostscript; the damage is done by the action of priting the PDF file. Once the PDF has been turned into a bitmap, the only way to get the search functionality back is going to be to put it through OCR software, and then overlay invisible text over the top of the bitmap, in the PDF file. Not impossible, but Ghostscript doesn't do that, its not OCR software. Of course, you still haven't supplied an example file so I could be wrong. Perhaps you need to rethink your approach.